# How to apply df.loc[] to multiple rows and apply transformation?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a transformation to all my rows in df["Text_str"] so I can make use of my padding function.

So far I can test manually by doing df.loc[i, "Text_str"] but I have rows of text I need to go through and append the results to the df.

How can I turn df.loc[i, "Text_str"] into a function, or better yet, perhaps apply it to the padding function?

```py
# percentage of words that are considered stopwords
def padding(text):
    #from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    nltk.download('stopwords')
    stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
    text = re.findall('[A-z]+', text)
    content = [w for w in text if w.lower() in stopwords] # you can calculate %stopwords using "in"
    return round(float(len(content)) / len(text), 2)

test_data = df.loc[1, "Text_str"]

print(padding(test_data))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Example of 1 row of df["Text_str"]

```
0    Parker-Hannifin Corp. (NYSE: Q2 2016 Earnings Call January 26, 2016 11:00 am ET Executives Jon P. Marten - Executive Vice President-Finance & Adminstration and Chief Financial Officer Thomas L. Williams - Chairman & Chief Executive Officer Lee C. Banks - President and Chief Operating Officer Analysts James A. Picariello - KeyBanc Capital Markets, Inc. Nicole Deblase - Morgan Stanley & Co. LLC Eli Lustgarten - Longbow Research LLC Andrew M. Casey - Wells Fargo Securities LLC Ann P. Duignan - JPMorgan Securities LLC Jamie L. Cook - Credit Suisse Securities (NYSE: Joseph Alfred Ritchie - Goldman Sachs & Co. Nathan Jones - Stifel, Nicolaus & Co., Inc. Andrew Burris Obin - Bank of America Merrill Lynch Joel Gifford Tiss - BMO Capital Markets (United States) Operator Good day, ladies and gentlemen, and welcome to the Parker-Hannifin Corp. Fiscal 2016 Second Quarter Earnings Conference Call. At this time, all participants are in a listen-only mode. Later, we will conduct a question-and-an...
```

Type:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: What's the output of df.head()?

Comment: Ooops, should be up now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
df['Padding'] = [padding(x) for x in list(df.loc[:,'Text_str'])]
```